# python socket server/client protocol with unstable client connection

Tags: python, sockets

I have a threaded python socket server that opens a new thread for each connection.

The thread is a very simple communication based on question and answer.
Basically client sends initial data transmission, server takes it run an external app that does stuff to the transmission and returns a reply that the server will send back and the loop will begin again until client disconnects.

Now because the client will be on a mobile phone thus an unstable connection I get left with open threads no longer connected and because the loop starts with recv it is rather difficult to break on lost connectivity this way.

I was thinking on adding a send before the recv to test if connection is still alive but this might not help at all if the client disconnects after my failsafe send as the client sends a data stream every 5 seconds only.

I noticed the recv will break sometimes but not always and in those cases I am left with zombie threads using resources.

Also this could be a solid vulnerability for my system to be DOSed.
I have looked through the python manual and Googled since thursday trying to find something for this but most things I find are related to client and non blocking mode.

Can anyone point me in the right direction towards a good way on fixing this issue?

**Code samples:**

Listener:

```
serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversocket.bind(addr)
serversocket.listen(2)
logg("Binded to port: " + str(port))

# Listening Loop
while 1:
  clientsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
  threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(clientsocket, clientaddr,port,)).start()

# This is useless as it will never get here
serversocket.close()
```

Handler:

```
  # Socket connection handler (Threaded)
  def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr, port):
    clientsocket.settimeout(15)

    # Loop till client closes connection or connection drops
    while 1:
      stream = ''
      while 1:
        ending = stream[-6:] # get stream ending
        if ending == '.$$$$.':
          break

        try:
          data = clientsocket.recv(1)
        except:
          sys.exit()

        if not data:
          sys.exit()
          # this is the usual point where thread is closed when a client closes connection normally

        stream += data

      # Clear the line ending
      stream = base64.b64encode(stream[:-6])

      # Send data to be processed
      re = getreply(stream)

      # Send response to client
      try:
        clientsocket.send(re + str('.$$$$.'))
      except:
        sys.exit()
```

As you can see there are three conditions that at least one should trigger exit if connection fails but sometimes they do not.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the code? Are you using a Queue.queue? Using a Queue.queue enables you to see if you have jobs waiting for your threads, you can then set a timeout on the threads and if they don't get anything - they finish.

Comment: I am not using twisted or anything else. Will ad the relevant code.

Comment: Two things come to my mind - you could try the .timeout() function of a socket object to close clientsocket after a few seconds of inactivity on the socket (http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout). Or I also believe that slightly rewriting the multithreading part of you program to use a Queue. Using a Queue has the benefits of setting the number of threads you want to allow as well handling the jobs passed to those threads. I just found out about it recently and it blew my mind.

Comment: serversocket.settimeout(10) makes the server disconnect and clientsocket.settimeout(10) does not appear to work. after a while (sometimes hours sometimes days - my guess it depends on how and when the client just stops to communicate as it loses connection).

Comment: I added a comment in the Handler where it usually terminates if connection is closed normally via FIN.

Comment: clientsocket.settimeout should work i.e., recv/send should raise an exception on timeout. How did you test it? Also use sendall instead of send; shutdown/close sockets on errors. Why do you use sys.exit instead of return? Why do you use `str` around `'.$$$$.'`?

Comment: What is the difference between send and send all? yeah that str is extra the ending used to be variable based on various things and some numeric. Eventually we decided to simplify. I tested with an Android app and it works swell when I test but after a day or so I end up having open threads that did not close. I have added logging that also counts no of open threads.

Comment: `send` doesn't guarantee that it sends all input.

Comment: @tntu: Are you still looking for help with this problem?  If so, can you make sure the code above is up to date and run the linux command `ss -taeon` and post the header line and a line from a hung connection.  That will help with figuring out what is happening at the network level.

Comment: @JimP That was helpfull a bit. It shows me all connections as CLOSE-WAIT ino:100653126 sk:ffff880236a4f240 If you can explain what they mean that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @tntu: Ok, [CLOSE-WAIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) means that the remote side has closed the socket, but your side has not yet.  Did the output of `ss -taeon` show any data in the inbound or outbound buffers?

Are you sure the thread is hanging on the read?  Is it possible that the thread is hanging on the write or maybe the thread exited and the socket is being held open by something else with a reference to it.  I would try adding an explicit `close` call on right before your `sys.exit` calls.

Comment: @JimP No data 0 0. I have added an explicit close for the client connection before the thread exit. Will see how it behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I think that `threaded` idea in this case is not good. As you do not need to process/do a lot of stuff in these threads (workers?) and most of the time these threads are waiting for socket (is the blocking operation, isn't it?) I would advice to read about [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). According to sockets this pattern is extremly useful, becouse you can do all stuff in one thread. You are communicate with one socket at a time, but the rest of connections are just waiting to data so there is almost no loss. When you send several bytes you just check that maybe another connection requires carrying. You can read about [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)
and [epoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll).

In python there is several libraries to play with this nicly:

- libev (c library wrapper) - [pyev](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyev/)
- [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)
- [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

I used tornado in some projects and it is done this task very good. Libev is nice also, but is a c-wrapper so it is a little bit `low-level` (but very nice for some tasks).

Comment: Actually I do need threads. I have an high volume of simultaneous connections and they can't wait in line. They need to be processed immediately. Speed is of the essence. As I mentioned the clients are mobile phones and there is quite a few of them. If they have to wait in line eventually most of them would time out before they got their turn.

Comment: Please read about [c10k problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) and see [presentation about nginx](http://serverfault.com/a/86691) and how that problem is resolved (and see benchmarks of threaded/worker architecture vs event-driven in IO tasks). You can see that worker model is not a "speedy" way in this case. So, if you do not do computations, I suggest using this approach.

Comment: Well that is just it. There are a very large number of computations queries, external application calls and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So you should use `socket.settimeout(float)` with the `clientsocket` like one of the comments suggested.

The reason you don't see any difference is, when you call `socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])` and the timeout runs out an `socket.timeout` exception is thrown and you catch that exception and exit.

```
try:
      data = clientsocket.recv(1)
except:
      sys.exit()
```

should be somthing like:

```
try:
      data = clientsocket.recv(1)
except timeout:
      #timeout occurred
      #handle it
      clientsocket.close()
      sys.exit()
```

Comment: my problem is script does not actually timeout and exit

Comment: which script is not running in the timeout the server script or the client script?

Comment: from the python docs: Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.

Comment: in a thread will exit the thread, same thing as return, but I will however take your idea and use it, but that is just a side issue not my main problem.

Comment: the handler does not time out sometimes. it is quite difficult to replicate as it occurs in a very unpredictable fashion even though the client app is the same the only difference is the different phones it is installed on but I did not notice a particular phone causing it

Comment: just a shoot in the dark but did you checked for dead locks?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock
So one threads waits for another to finish while the other does the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18219/discussion-between-raphael-ahrens-and-tntu)